# Ошибка Fatal error: Cannot redeclare помогите пожалуйста

Tags: функции, php, mysql

Есть такая функция

```
<?
            $message_query= mysql_query("SELECT u.id,p.*,u.username,u.family,u.avatar
       FROM messages p, users u
       WHERE CASE
       WHEN p.group_hash = '$hash'
       THEN p.from_id = u.id
       END
       OR (
       p.from_id ='$id'
       )
       Order by p.timemsg ASC") or die(mysql_error());

      while ($run_message = mysql_fetch_array($message_query)) {
  $from_id = $run_message['from_id'];
  $message = $run_message['message'];
        $user2 = $run_post['from_id_to'];
  $timemsg = $run_message['timemsg'];
  $from_username = $run_message['username'];
  $from_family = $run_message['family'];
  $from_avatar = $run_message['avatar'];
  $from_id = $run_message['id'];

function xTimeAgo ($oldTime, $newTime, $timeType) {
            $timeCalc = strtotime($newTime) - strtotime($oldTime);
            if ($timeType == "x") {
                if ($timeCalc = 60) {
                    $timeType = "m";
                }
                if ($timeCalc = (60*60)) {
                    $timeType = "h";
                }
                if ($timeCalc = (60*60*24)) {
                    $timeType = "d";
                }
            }
            if ($timeType == "s") {
                $timeCalc .= " seconds ago";
            }
            if ($timeType == "m") {
                $timeCalc = round($timeCalc/60) . " minutes ago";
            }
            if ($timeType == "h") {
                $timeCalc = round($timeCalc/60/60) . " hours ago";
            }
            if ($timeType == "d") {
                $timeCalc = round($timeCalc/60/60/24) . " days ago";
            }
            return $timeCalc;
        }
?>
Но почему то выдает ошибку подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция с таким названием уже была объявлена в скрипте. Вы старую реализацию удалить не забыли?

Comment: Нет.Есть скрипт вывода сообщений и вот функция времени.Но почему то не работает не пойму почему.

Comment: Такое сообщение выдаёт если функция написана больше одного раза. Переименуйте.

Comment: Пробовал переименовывать но все равно, сейчас вот отредактирую запись вывод весь скину.ПОсмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: @Andrey Kartavtsev значит дважды подключаете файл с функцией

Comment: Спасибо большое, разобрался.